# CSS Grid child element not occupy the full width of the column

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS Grid declared as following:

***UPDATE:** I've inserted a running example*

```css
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
    align-items: stretch;
    gap: 2.5rem;
}

.parent li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-self: stretch !important;
}
```

But the child elements don't occupy the full width of the column.

The output result is like that:

[image]

Note that the card that expanding, having big size images while the one that doesn't stretch it has a smaller image size.

The overall structure of the card is like that:

```html
<li class="ais-Hits-item">
    <div class="property-card">
        <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
                <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                    <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
                </div>
                <ul class="property-card__features">
                    <li>Feature #1</li>
                    <li>Feature #1</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button">View</a>
        </div>
        <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info">
                <span class="property-card__listing-type">val</span>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Detached House</a> 
            <figure>
                <img src="img_url" class="property-card__image" alt="alt text">
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

```css
body {
    background: #AFAFAF;
}

.ais-Hits-list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
    align-items: stretch;
    gap: 2.5rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ais-Hits-list > .ais-Hits-item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0px;
    --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
    --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
    box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow);
    justify-self: stretch !important;
}

.ais-Hits-item:first-of-type, .ais-InfiniteHits-item:first-of-type {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.ais-Hits-item, .ais-InfiniteHits-item {
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    font-size: .875rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.25rem;
}

.property-card {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    border-radius: 0.375rem;
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    --tw-drop-shadow: drop-shadow(0 4px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.07)) drop-shadow(0 2px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.06));
    filter: var(--tw-blur) var(--tw-brightness) var(--tw-contrast) var(--tw-grayscale) var(--tw-hue-rotate) var(--tw-invert) var(--tw-saturate) var(--tw-sepia) var(--tw-drop-shadow);
    transition-property: all;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    transition-duration: 300ms;
}

.property-card__info-data {
    padding: 0.75rem;
}

.property-card__price-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 0.5rem;
}

.property-card__price {
    font-size: 1.875rem;
    line-height: 2.25rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(45 84 119 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.property-card__image-container {
    position: relative;
    order: -9999;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.375rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.375rem;
}

.property-card__rr-code {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    gap: 0.75rem;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(190 23 32 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-top: 0.25rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.property-card__listing-info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    gap: 0.75rem;
}

.property-card__listing-type {
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(30 41 59 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-top: 0.25rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.property-card__listing-category {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(30 41 59 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-top: 0.25rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
    transition-property: all;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    transition-duration: 150ms;
}

.property-card__image {
    aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.375rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.375rem;
    border-style: none;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<ol class="ais-Hits-list">
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/100x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ol>
```

Do you may have any idea why the child elements not stretching by default independent from the image width ?

Comment: Hey there. The issue is related to the `div.property-card` which is a flex and doesn't have the `flex-grow.` if you add it will fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code. But I not getting any proble.

If you face any problem. Then I think you need to put proper all code here.

And two to three css is unuseable.

1. .parent li in this use align-items:stretch.
2. .parent align-items:strentch

Answer (score 1):

The problem resides in your `div.property-card`.
Your image size is relative to your container, but your container size is relative to your image.
To fix this issue, you can add `flex-grow: 1`, it will make your container grow to fit `li.ais-Hits-item` which has its size defined by the grid.

```css
body {
    background: #AFAFAF;
}

.ais-Hits-list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
    align-items: stretch;
    gap: 2.5rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ais-Hits-list > .ais-Hits-item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0px;
    --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
    --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
    box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow);
    justify-self: stretch !important;
}

.ais-Hits-item:first-of-type, .ais-InfiniteHits-item:first-of-type {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.ais-Hits-item, .ais-InfiniteHits-item {
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    font-size: .875rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.25rem;
}

.property-card {
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    border-radius: 0.375rem;
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    --tw-drop-shadow: drop-shadow(0 4px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.07)) drop-shadow(0 2px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.06));
    filter: var(--tw-blur) var(--tw-brightness) var(--tw-contrast) var(--tw-grayscale) var(--tw-hue-rotate) var(--tw-invert) var(--tw-saturate) var(--tw-sepia) var(--tw-drop-shadow);
    transition-property: all;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    transition-duration: 300ms;
}

.property-card__info-data {
    padding: 0.75rem;
}

.property-card__price-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 0.5rem;
}

.property-card__price {
    font-size: 1.875rem;
    line-height: 2.25rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(45 84 119 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.property-card__image-container {
    position: relative;
    order: -9999;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.375rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.375rem;
}

.property-card__rr-code {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    gap: 0.75rem;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(190 23 32 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-top: 0.25rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.property-card__listing-info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    gap: 0.75rem;
}

.property-card__listing-type {
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(30 41 59 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-top: 0.25rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.property-card__listing-category {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(30 41 59 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-top: 0.25rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
    transition-property: all;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    transition-duration: 150ms;
}

.property-card__image {
    aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.375rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.375rem;
    border-style: none;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<ol class="ais-Hits-list">
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/100x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ais-Hits-item">
      <div class="property-card">
         <div class="property-card__info-data">
            <div class="property-card__data">
               <div class="property-card__price-wrapper">
                  <p class="property-card__price">xxx €</p>
               </div>
               <ul class="property-card__features"><li>Feature #1</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__button" title="View more details">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="property-card__image-container">
            <span class="property-card__rr-code">val</span>
            <div class="property-card__listing-info"><span class="property-card__listing-type">Sale</span></div>
            <a href="#" class="property-card__listing-category">Val</a>
            <figure><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="property-card__image" alt="Photo"></figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ol>
```

**Edit**: I saw Nath's comment after writing this.